# MS SQL services restart will remove user setting in tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I wrote a stored procedure in 'test' database.This procedure will create temp table to tempdb.

I found when SQL service restart.
It lost my user in tempdb and
procedure has no permission to access in.

I need to add user again in tempdb: security-> user.

### User Setting:

Database-Level Roles : `public & db_owner`

Fixed-Database Roles :  `db_owner`

When service restart I want my user setting keep it.
Is anything can to that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my tempdb reset permissions when the server is rebooted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315897/why-does-my-tempdb-reset-permissions-when-the-server-is-rebooted)

Answer (score 1):

Objects are in `tempdb` only persist until they are dropped or the instance is restarted. This is by design. "tempdb" means "Temporary DataBase". The objects within are inherently temporary, as the database is rebuilt each time the server restarts.

From [TempDB Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Operations within **TempDB** are minimally logged so that transactions can be rolled back. **TempDB** is re-created every time SQL Server is started so that the system always starts with a clean copy of the database. Temporary tables and stored procedures are dropped automatically on disconnect, and no connections are active when the system is shut down. Therefore, there is never anything in **TempDB** to be saved from one session of SQL Server to another. Backup and restore operations are not allowed on **TempDB**.

If you want permanent objects, you should create them in a user database, such as your `test` database.

Answer (score 1):

When SQL Service restarts then **TempDB** automatically re-created.Means Everytime it copies the structure of **Model** DB.If you want  the user should be existed in **TempDB** even after restarted then you need to create the user in **Model** DB.But for security reasons i would suggest you to create the user in **test** DB only.